# Oracle function dynamic column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a function, and I want to determine the name of the column in run time. For this I am passing one variable as an argument, like `column_name`.

Below is the code with the function:

```
l_column_name as varchar2(100)

Begin 

If(column_name='emp_name')
  Then 
  l_column_name:=EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME
End If;

   begin
 select l_column_name from employee
end;
```

In above code, `l_column_name:=EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME` is giving the error

> Not allowed in this context.

Any help is much appreicated.

Regards,
Chaitu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, you can not do this.

You need to look into using the PL/SQL Execute Immediate: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm

```
declare
  l_column_name as varchar2(100);
  l_column_results as VARCHAR2(100);
begin
  if (column_name = 'emp_name') then
     l_column_name := 'EMPLOYEE.EMP_NAME';
  end if;
  query := 'SELECT ' || l_column_name || ' from employeee';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query INTO l_column_results;
end;
```

Comment: yes, it's the only way to get results from the query back into your pl/sql code.